# Solving and replacing solution for solving again

Tags: equation-solving

Given some equation to solve

```
S1=Solve[f[x,z]==g[x,z],x]//Simplify
```

which produces something like

```
x->xsol[z]
```

I write another equation that must use the result above, so

```
S2=Solve[h[x,y,z]==j[x,y,z],y]/.S1//Simplify
```

but it gives

```
y-> y[(x->xsol),z]
```

I mean, it didnt replace `x=xsol`. How can I improve this steps?

Comment: Move the `/.S1` inside the `Solve` and attach it to the equation instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the replacement, i.e. `/.S1` inside the solver. That is,

```
S2=Solve[h[x,y,z]==j[x,y,z]/.S1,y]//Simplify
```